# "without" vs. "minus"

Tags: prepositions

> Minus its prop, the gesture seems overlarge.
>
> And in the corrido waltz ''Nacho Verduzco'' (minus its story of drugs and guns), John Sherba's violin, [...]
>
> It looks like a capital letter R, minus its vertical leg, and with two added horizontal lines through the [...]
>
> Enter a flamingo, static and probably plastic, minus a lawn, just as the potato is minus its couch.

The sentences above show that "minus", meaning "without" can appear.

Question are: Is it common this usage of "minus"? If so, what are the cases in which "minus" is not interchangeable with "without"?

Answer (score 3):

*Minus* is very common in this sense, as is *plus* in the sense *with* or *and*.

They are generally used to lend an active sense of addition or subtraction to the basic sense of presence or absence. Thus:

- *a capital letter R, minus its vertical leg* means something like “R with its vertical leg **taken away**”.
- *a capital letter R, plus two horizontal lines* would mean something like “R with two lines **added**”. *Plus* (but not *minus*) is also used to introduce a sentence, with the sense *Moreover* or *Furthermore*.

These are informal uses and should probably not be used in the most formal discourse—until you find that they are in fact used there!

That *minus* may replace *without* in this manner does not imply that *without* may replace *minus*. *Four minus two* may not be expressed as *four without two*, and *the square root of minus one* may not be expressed as *the square root of without one*.

Answer (score 0):

One can use *minus*, *sans*, *save for* and even *absent* in place of *without*. More common, though, would be *without*, or *except for*.

> Except for the rain on Tuesday, it would have been a perfect week.

There are times the word *minus* might sound less natural than *without*, such as at the beginning of this sentence:

> Without George's compass, we would have never found our way back to the tent.

I suppose one could use *minus* there, but I don't think it adds much, and it might even make the sentence sound a little more awkward. This is hard to explain, but I think some of the less common expressions tend to make the prose sound more poetic or dramatic:

> “Excel is relatively easy to use and learn, save for the creation of advanced macros.”
>    (from a software review in *InfoWorld*, Nov 18, 1985)

As I said, any of them can be used, but *without* is by far the most common. As an exercise for the reader, add "without the" to [this Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=minus+the%2Cabsent+the%2Csans+the%2Cexcept+for+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), and observe how the others flatline, save for *except for the*.